# I want, when user is logged in in application A then he should be logged in Application B in Laravel on same server(localhost or cPanel)

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter

Suppose I have two web applications. One is in Laravel and second one is in CodeIgniter. When the user is logged into the Laravel application he should be also logged into the CodeIgniter application when user redirected to CodeIgniter application.

Can any one can explain me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will be very rare case since both Laravel and codeignitor are different in there structure. In your case if you want to communicate between this two application in single server means you can use memcached to store session.

Answer (score 0):

*Codeigniter* : write a function in controller that return logged in user id.

*Laravel*: 
call that CI function and get user id then use `Auth::loginUsingId(1);`